# XMLSerializer not reading all Elements

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a class used to serialize and deserialize via XMLSerializer. ExportSteps is another class which implements IXmlSerializer for custom serialization.

My issue is it's not reading and setting any properties after it reads exportSteps. If I move IsNew and Test2 above Steps, it works fine. I don't think that is a valid solution though, what if I need two custom serialized classes?

```
public class PublishOptions
{


    [XmlElement( "test" )]
    public bool Test { get; set; }

    [XmlElement( "exportSteps" )]
    public ExportSteps Steps { get; set; } <-- implements IXmlSerializable

    [XmlElement( "isNew" )]
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }

    [XmlElement( "test2" )]
    public bool Test2{ get; set; }}
}

var test = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as PublishOptions;
```

XML (Example):

```
<publishingOptions>
  <test>true</test>
  <exportSteps>     
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
  </exportSteps>
  <isNew>true</isNew>
  <test2>true</test2>
</publishingOptions>
```

Comment: what does the XML Structure look like Shah also instead of Stream have  you thought about using XMLReader

Comment: Edited with sample XML. Note this is a simplified version.

Comment: In your sample you say the element is named 'exportOptions' and in your code you labled it 'exportSteps'  was this a typo?  They should match names otherwise it could cause internal errors when trying to deserialize.

Comment: Fixed that up, it was just a typo, I use the same class to serialize the xml, so they should matchup. I'm just wondering if a custom class has to be put last in the order of elements. If I re-order and put it last it seems to read everything fine.

Comment: Property IsNew should be `XMLElement("isNew")`

Comment: I think you should definitely post your implementation of IXmlSerializable. Appears your custom serialization logic may be throwing things off.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, it was in the ReadXml method. The reader was exiting the custom reader in the middle of an element. This caused anything after the custom serializer to fail.